# What is needed to make the IF statement run instead of the ELSE statement?

Tags: c++

I am making a very simple game. The objective is to add two numbers together, compare the player's answer to the computer's answer, and tell the player whether they answered correctly or not.

```
int randnum = rand() % 100;
int number[2];
int answer = number[0] + number[1];
int playeranswer = 0;
number[0] = randnum;
number[1] = randnum * randnum - 23;

cout << number[0] << "+" << number[1] << endl;
cout << "What's your answer to the question?" << endl;
cin >> playeranswer;

if (playeranswer == answer)
{
    cout << "Yep, that's the right answer" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Wrong" << endl;
    cout << "The answer is..." << number[0] + number[1] << endl;
    cout << "Your answer was..." << playeranswer << endl;
}
```

I expect it to tell me "Yep, that's the right answer" but it tells me "Wrong". The `else` statement always runs even if the two numbers are obviously the same.

I have already tried replacing the arrays with different variables.

A good example of an error I am getting

[image]

Comment: You are calculating the computer's answer before generating the random numbers in the expression. Move `int answer = number[0] + number[1];` down to after assigning the random numbers to the array entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning value to `answer` variable before assigning value to `number[0]` and `number[1]`. Assign value to `answer` after assigning value to `number[0]` and `number[1]`:

```
    int randnum = rand() % 100;
    int number[2];

    int playeranswer = 0;
    number[0] = randnum;
    number[1] = randnum * randnum - 23;
    int answer = number[0] + number[1];
```